# Confuse about css background image stretch

Tags: css, background, background-image

I have an image which width is `50px` and height is `20px`, then I set it as a div's background:

```
background: url('close.png') no-repeat 0 0;
width: 71.875px;
height: 28.75px;
position: absolute;
top: 50px;
background-position:center;
background-size:100%,100%;
```

although the div's width and height is not as the same as image, but the ratio is the same, both are `5: 2`. but the result is strange:

[image]

[image]

There exist a gap line between the div and its above element. It seems the image doesn't stretch at the top.

Why this happened? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use commas in css rules

`background-size:100%,100%;` should be `background-size:100%;`

Answer (score 0):

you should,

```
background-size:100%;
```